# what code should i use ?? wordpress and css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have problem with my text in wordpress I took this code from the source code and tried to write CSS in my wordpress template.

Code:

```
<div id="big-video-vid" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-controls-disabled vjs-has-started vjs-playing vjs-user-active"  style="width: 784px; height: 441px; display: block; top: 0px; left: -61.5px;">
```

I want to change the top and left in CSS in my template window..

Here is the website to check 
[www.produsers.qa](http://www.produsers.qa)

....... the glitch I need to fix in : venue to be confirmed

Comment: your link does not work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not good practice to do this (override inline styles) and would be better that you can remove the inline styling from your html file, BUT you can do this by adding !important to the relevant css classes. So you could add the following to your external stylesheet

```
#big-video-vid {
  top: new-value-here !important;
  left: new-value-here !important;
}
```

so the styles would read (adapt the numerical values to what you need)

```
#big-video-vid {
  top: 150px !important;
  left: 100px !important;
}
```

But this is definitely somewhat a "hack" and should really only be done as a last resort in a situation where you cannot alter inline styles as I said

Comment: i wrote it like this 


#big-video-vid {
  top: new-150xp !important;
  left: new-80xp !important;
}

is this correct ?

warning window pop-up 
says : use of !important
Expected ( <margin-width> | inherit ) but found ‘new-90xp

Comment: remove the 'new-' replace 'new-value-here' with the value you require

Comment: i wrote it like this 


#big-video-vid {
  top: 'new-value-here'-150xp !important;
  left: 'new-value-here'-80xp !important;
}

is this correct ?

X sign window pop-up 
says : Expected (<margin-width> | inherit) but found ‘ ’new-value-here’ ‘ .
Expected RBRACE at line 56, col 25.

Comment: answer updated to reflect numerical values. I'd recommend you have a good look at some basic css examples over at w3schools or similar - looks like you need to learn quite a few basics and it's a great resource.

Comment: thanks you very much .. i didn't saw what i should write .. you been so helpfull ..